# JBoss Fuse - Can we replace dependency on ActiveMQ to WebSphereMQ?

Tags: jbossfuse

I would like to avoid dependency on ActiveMQ. Is there a way to make JBossFuse to use WebSphereMQ ? (I'm assuming activeMQ is required for framework to run - internal dependency)

The description on jboss fuse site reads like..

```
Core messaging is provided by Apache ActiveMQ, services framework (SOAP, XML/HTTP, RESTful HTTP)...
```

PS:
Arguements like "it would be innefficient, expensive" etc, need not be considered at this stage. Reason for prefering WebSphereMQ is beyond my control.

Answer (score 1):

No you can use JBoss Fuse without ActiveMQ at all. For example the minimal distribution does not come with AMQ pre-installed.

JBoss Fuse allows you to slice and dice what you want pre-installed.

If you want to use WebSphereMQ then you can do that, though that would be under the assumption that WebSphereMQ as a server is running in another JVM / box. And that JBoss Fuse would act as a client to that broker. If so you can install the WebSphereMQ Java Client JARs in Jboss Fuse and use that.